# php imap mark email as read on office365 mail

Tags: php, email, imap, office365

I had a function to read from gmail then mark it as read and it has been working fine. 
We recently switched to office 365 and now we can't mark the mails as read any more. I got no error message. Any help will be appreciated.

Related code:

```
$authhost = "{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX";
$email = "blablabla@companyname.com";//dummy text. I swear i dont have typo here
$emailPassword = "NotGonnaTellYa";//dummy text. No typo here.

$mailbox = imap_open($authhost, $email, $emailPassword);
$mails = imap_search($mailbox, "ALL");

foreach ($mails as $mail) {
    $mail_headers = imap_headerinfo($mailbox, $mail);
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($mailbox, $mail);
    /*
      do something magically to process the emails then save it to local..
     */
    imap_delete($mailbox, $mail);
}

imap_expunge($mailbox);
imap_close($mailbox);
```

I have given the folders Owner permission in office 365 mail but failed to find any settings about allow IMAP to delete mails.

I have tried using CL_EXPUNGE to open the mail box but no luck either.

Comment: uh, are you trying to mark them read, or trying to delete them?

Comment: @Max Im trying to mark them as read then delete them. We want to keep the mailbox clean. If i cant do both then just delete them is acceptable. I doubt the possibility of only be able to do one of the actions tho

Comment: office 365 must be exchange and gmail god knows what. try to contact office 365 and ask if there is any documentation on how to manipulate the mailbox with external scripts.

Comment: If you're hard deleting them, like you appear to be doing, there's no point in marking them read first.

Comment: @Max You do have a point but the problem is i cant modify either of those state.

Comment: Do you only have readonly access to the folder somehow?  How are you authenticating?  What does your $mailbox string look like?

Comment: @max I have full access of that email account, not so sure about readonly access as i dont know where to check it. Please see edit for $mailbox string.